# Set div background as photo taken with Camera

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I'm building a mobile app using PhoneGap in Android and am trying to set the background of a div to the photo that is taken using the camera.

I've got the camera working fine (code below), however after taking the photo I want to immediately set the background image of the body div as the photo instead of just showing the user their photo.

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

// Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// PhoneGap is ready to be used!
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

  //set the background here?
  $('#wrapper').css("background-image", "url(imageData.jpg)"); 
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true }); 
}

// A button will call this function
//
function getPhoto(source) {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

// Called if something bad happens.
// 
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

To set the background in previous code, i've used the following:

```
$('#wrapper').css("background-image", "url(imageData.jpg)")
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: what exactly isn't working for you? what keeps you from doing $('#wrapper').css("background-image',largeimage)? or is the question about the user not getting the camera cancel,accept screen>?

Comment: So what are the issues you're having? Whats going wrong?

Comment: That line of code I suggested at the bottom isn't working, it's just to give an idea of what I want.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is the URI and not the base64 data

add

```
$('#wrapper').css("background-image", "url("+imageURI+")")
```

at the bottom of function onPhotoURISuccess and use it as your success handler in the call to capturePhoto(). I just got this working for me using pretty much the exact same code (the sample from phonegap's camera API docs)